# Python. Connect to HTTPS forward proxy with client certificate

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, proxy

I will trying to connect to site using https forward proxy. And proxy needed client certificate/key pair for establish an ssl connection.
Curl example:

```bash
curl https://example.com --proxy https://example.proxy.com --proxy-cert cert.pem --proxy-key key.pem
```

How to reproduce this logic in python? In `requests` library this code does not work:

```py
import requests
requests.get(
    'https://example.com',
    proxies={'https': 'https://example.proxy.com'},
    cert=('./cert.pem', './key.pem')
)
```

Exception response:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Unable to connect to proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

This is looks like requests trying to use cert params to secure traffic between client and destination site, not proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Found some variant with `ssl` and `urllib3`:

Minimal reproduce code example:

```py
import ssl
import urllib3

# create ssl context with client cert/key pair
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('./cert.pem', './key.key')
context.load_verify_locations('./ca_certs.pem') # also our custom ca bundle

# create urllib3 Proxy object and setup our context to proxy-ssl-context
proxy = urllib3.ProxyManager('https://example.proxy.com', proxy_ssl_context=context)

# do request
r = proxy.request('GET', 'https://example.com')
print(r.status) # return 200
```